# Bootstrap Grid System - To much empty space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a Layout like this when the screen ist large:
A | B1
A | B2
C | B3
C | B4
When the screen is small i want like this:
A
A
B1
B2
B3
B4
C
C

With my solution the small screen layout is ok. But on large screen is like this:
A | B1
A | B2
* | B3
* | B4
C
C

- = this is empty space. I want C is direct below A for large screen. A than B than C for small screen

See in picture:
[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:yellow">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">A</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">B</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">B1</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">B2</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">B3</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">B4</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">B5</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              ...
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:blue">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">c</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put it in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: @carinlynchin, in principle it's better to just use [so] snippets and have it inside the question itself, ***just as Xeddon had it*** at the time you requested fiddle/codepen. If you prefer any  external snippet websites, you should copy/paste what user provided, rather than asking the user to do it, IMHO. Note I too prefer `jsFiddle` as it supports `scss`, but I don't ask people to provide an external fiddle when they have SO snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Use provided `.col-*-push-*` and `.col-*-pull-*` utility classes:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
      <div>B3</div>
      <div>B4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
      <div>C</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note Bootstrap is mobile first. You need to put them into *normal* order on mobile and `pull`/`push` on larger sizes.

To reset a pull or push on a larger size you need to specify a push/pull of 0 on the larger size. For example, the following only pushes on `sm` but stops pushing on `md` and above, allowing B's to group in center on larger screen sizes:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6  col-md-3">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-0">
      <div>B3</div>
      <div>B4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-0">
      <div>C</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**After update,** it looks like you are looking for a masonry layout but didn't formulate as such. Bootstrap cannot produce this layout by itself, so you need to use an extra library. Common options are Masonry, Isotope and Bootstrap Waterfall.

Here's how to use [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) on Bootstrap `.col-`s and keep it from breaking your layout on small widths:

1. Load jQuery (js)
2. Load Bootstrap (css + js)
3. Load Masonry (js)
4. Place each of A's B's and C's in distinct `.col-*-*` of the same `.row` parent while adding a specific class to that row (I used `masonry` here).
5. Place `col-xs-12` on each of your `col-*-*`s. If you don't do this, `masonry` will display them as columns, side by side, below the breaking point, if the content allows it.
6. On `window.load` event, run `$('.masonry').masonry()` (replace `.masonry` selector with your own, if you used a different class name on parent `.row`).

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.masonry').masonry();
})
```

```css
/* you don't really need CSS for this to work 
 * code below is aimed more at making the snippet look good on SO
 */

.a-s {background-color: rgba(255,255,0,.07);}
.b-s {background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.07);}
.c-s {background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.07);}

.body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.masonry {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row masonry">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 a-s">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 b-s">
      <div>B1</div>
      <div>B2</div>
      <div>B3</div>
      <div>B4</div>
      <div>B5</div>
      <div>B6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 c-s">
      <div>C</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note I don't necessarily recommend Masonry. I personally prefer Bootstrap Waterfall (it's closer to the Pinterest script) but it's not as easy to use as Masonry. I know for a fact Isotope is also a very solid and reliable option but I didn't have the chance to use it as of yet.

Comment: i think this is not what i'm looking for. I edited my code and add some background color and uploded a picture to explain better

Comment: @Xeddon, that is not something Bootstrap can do. Considering each of the colors is a `col-md-6`, use any of: Isotope, Masonry or Bootstrap Waterfall plugins at page load on the contents of your row.